# Example using Cutkosky cutting rules where a cut is not allowed by violation of conservation of momentum

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams

Using $(+,-,-,-)$ the Cutkosky cutting rules are stated as

1. Cut through the diagram in any way that can put all of the cut propagators
   on-shell without violating momentum conservation.
2. For each cut, replace $\frac{1}{p^2 −m^2 +i \varepsilon} → −2i\pi \delta(p^2 − m^2) \theta(p^0 )$.
3. Sum over all cuts.
4. The result is the discontinuity of the diagram, where $\text{Disc}(i\mathcal{M}) =
   −2\text{Im}\mathcal{M}$

I am trying to find a case where I can't put all the propagators on shell without violating conservation of momentum as stated in (1), but every case I can think it is perfectly fine to put all propagators on shell. So to answer this question I am asking for one example of that kind.